# how to validate user login using nodejs, javascript and nedb

Tags: javascript, node.js, nedb

Please help me, with the code below. am trying to validate login using javascript and nedb database. what am i do wrong.

login.html

```
 <form name="login" onSubmit="return validateForm();" action="home.html" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder=" Enter Username" required/>
     <br>
  <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Enter Password" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="Login">

 </form>
```

loginvalidate.js

This code is meant to validate, check and query the database for the username and password but it doesn't. it proceed to the home.html after ok is clicked when the dialog appears.

```
  const database = require('../scripts/logindb');


    function validateForm() {
    var user = document.loginform.user.value;
    var pass = document.loginform.pass.value;

     database.getAdmin(function(admin){

    var username = admin.username; 
    var password = admin.password;
    if ((user == username) && (pass == password)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert ("Error , please check your username and password");
        return false;
    }

     });        
}
```

logindb.js

```
var Datastore = require('nedb');

db = new Datastore({ filename: 'db/admin.db', autoload: true });

exports.addAdmin = function(firstname, lastname, username, password) 

{

var admin = {
        "firstname": firstname,
        "lastname": lastname,
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    };

db.insert(admin, function(err, newDoc) {

        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Table created!");
        db.close();

 });

 };

exports.getAdmin = function(fnc) {

    db.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        fnc(docs);

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `event` as a parameter to your `validateForm` function call:

```
<form name="login" onSubmit="return validateForm(event);" action="home.html" method="post">
```

Then inside your `validateForm` function use `preventDefault()` on the incoming `event` parameter:

```
function validateForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // other code here

  return false;
}
```

Also `require` is not part of regular JavaScript, it is used in [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) to load modules.

You will need to load your javascript files in your HTML:

```
<script src="../scripts/logindb"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will try it out.

Comment: Using `function validateForm(event) {event.preventDefault(); return false;}` prevented proceeding to the page. but the code in loginvalidate.js fails to query the database for the user name and password.